# Invalid asp.net navigating users to top of page when client side validation fails?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Using ASP.NET webforms, bootstrap, jquery.

My form submit:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSubmit" CssClass="btn btn-warning CausesValidation="true" runat="server">Submit</asp:LinkButton>
```

I have the following JS for client side validation:

```
 $("#ShortForm").click(function (evt) {
        var isValid = $("#ShortForm").formValidation('validate');
        if (!isValid)
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
```

I have both client side and server side validation checks. The form is located below the fold. If the client side check fails, the browser pulls the user to the top of the page. If the client side passes, but the server side fails, the browser does not change the position on the page. Why is this?

Comment: Exactly what do you need to achieve?

Comment: When the form is invalid on the client side, it does not maintain scroll position. No post back is occurring, since it failed client side validation (formvalidation function). I want it to maintain the scroll position.

Answer (score 1):

The browser maintains position after postback probably because your code is setting the [MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback(v=vs.100).aspx)  to true.

The browser scrolls to the top of the page after client validation failure because of code within the `formValidation` function.  I'm not familiar with this function (which JQuery plugin are you using for this?) but my guess is that you are using a validation suite that has a validation summary panel at the top of the page and the `.formValidation` function is scrolling the page so the user can see it.

Comment: Too much guessing, shouldn't this be a comment instead?

Answer (score 1):

The validation plugin  is formvalidation.io

This corrects the issue

```
 if (!$("#ShortForm").data('formValidation').isValid())
            evt.preventDefault();
     });
```

Could someone shed some light as to why this solves the issue? I'd like to understand the inner workings of why this works, and how the issue is occurring?